# Yoast Metadata API to adjust/override the meta description

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I wanted to use the following function to override the Yoast meta description:

```
add_filter('wpseo_metadesc','custom_meta');
function custom_meta( $desc ){

    if (/* do your test here to check template or any other values*/) {
        $desc = "Change the description";
    } 

    return $desc;
}
```

However, Yoast SEO support recommends the [Metadata API](https://developer.yoast.com/customization/apis/metadata-api/).

From this page, I understand I can use the `wpseo_metadesc` filter to adjust the `Meta_Description_Presenter`, but I am unsure how it is done; I am not a programmer.

I'd love some assistance to create some `functions.php` code that will grab the first 160 characters of the content if the meta description hasn't been set already.

Help appreciated.
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track here. You can use the `wpseo_metadesc` filter to alter the meta description any way you want. Check out below code, maybe it'll help you with your function.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'my_custom_meta_description' );
function my_custom_meta_description($description) {
    if ( !$description || empty($description) ) {
        global $post;
        $content = get_the_content($post->ID);
        if ( $content && !empty($content) ) {
            $description = substr($content, 0, 160);
        }
    }
    return $description;
}
```

I haven't tested the function so you may need to customize it for your need.

Comment: The goal is to overwrite the description. So I mean you should remove `if` check for `$description`, because he will overwrite the field with the characters from the post content.

Comment: Thanks for a fantastic answer. I can award the bounty in 3 hours, I'm told.

Comment: @bueltge, the goal was "grab the first 160 characters of the content if the meta description hasn't been set already". The IF checks if the description has already been set, otherwise it should be overwritten. So the IF is needed in this case if I'm correct.

Comment: @Steve, You're very welcome! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks man, adding this for new visitors: https://developer.yoast.com/features/seo-tags/descriptions/api/